# Backbone: cid after sync?

Tags: backbone.js

I'm testing Localstorage of Backbone with the following code. After saving the model, it's supposed to create an id and also a cid that is accessible at Model.cid. It's logging the id in the console (see below), but not the cid. Here's a fiddle that recreates the problem http://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/haE9K/2/

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

```
// Model Creation with defaults
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({

  localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("todos"), 
  defaults: {
       title:'new todo...',
       description:'missing...',
       done:false
  }
});

var myTodo = new Todo({}); 

console.log("Before save id:"+myTodo.get('id')); // Unique Id from Server
console.log("Before save cid:"+myTodo.cid); // Client side id
myTodo.save(); 

console.log(myTodo.get('title'));
console.log("After save id:"+myTodo.get('id'));
console.log("After save cid:"+myTodo.cid);
```

Console results

```
Before save id:undefined app.js:16
Before save cid:c0 app.js:17
new todo... app.js:20
After save id:99bc7f4c-8837-39f4-91e9-90760d8ee8cd app.js:21
After save cid:c0 app.js:22
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cid is created when the model is created and never change then. See the docs:

> A special property of models, the cid or client id is a unique
>   identifier automatically assigned to all models when they're first
>   created

Lets take a look in the constructing function of Backbone.Model:

```
  var Model = Backbone.Model = function(attributes, options) {
    .
    .
    .
    this.cid = _.uniqueId('c');
    .
    .
    .
  };
```

As you can see, the cid is created there using underscores uniqueId method.

Comment: ok, but then shouldn't it still be logging in the console?  The docs also say that it's accessible at Model.cid

Comment: Its logging `c0`, this is the cid of the model.